# How to get drop downs on top o figure Matlab App Designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want a drop down box to be in my figure. The figure will be updated based on drop down selection; thus I want drop down to remain on top. I think I want the drop down to be a child of the figure/axis, but I do not know where to put this in the script. I am using App Designer in MATLAB 2017B. The Mathworks Documentation doesn't provide an example. It states under UI Figure Parent/Chlildren, "empty GraphicsPlaceholder array (default) | 1-D array of component objects"

Can someone provide an example code. I am sure this is simple, but spent hours searching. Thanks in Advance.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

When I made the app, I added the drop downs, then the figure. The only way I could fix this was to delete the drop downs and then add them back. Unfortunately, the part of the script that Matlab creates the components is locked, so there was no way of moving the drop downs to after the figure. It took alot of work since I had a lot of drop downs, but its done.

Tim